# Javascript/JQuery custom HTML play button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

Since I did not like the default HTML5 audio controls, I was attempting to implement a simple button that would control this audio. Now, I am certainly no expert in Javascript/JQuery, and I could not figure out how to do this. What it does is it loops through a resultset and displays multiple songs into a table (so for each entry/song in the table, there should be a play/pause button. The only thing I found about this approach were hardcoded 'id' tags to control the audio, however this renders multiple of these audio elements with that id.

```
 <table>
       <tbody>
         {% for song in result %}
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <span>
                       <audio id="player" src="{{ song.audio_url }}"></audio>
                       <button onclick="playerAction(this)" class="butn butn--primary small"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                      </span>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
         {% endfor %}
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

How would I go about playing/pausing the closest audio element?

```
<script>
function playerAction(el){
    $(el).closest('player).play();
}
</script>
```

I have tried something like this, but it errors

All help is appreciated!

Note: The `{{}}` tags are Django variable items, just like the loop. This will render the audio links and the resultset itself

Comment: Have you tried $("table").find("#player"). play()? or replace each table with another container. You have syntax errors in your code,  maybe it will work too.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following:

```
<script>
function play(el){
    var audio = $(el).prev('#player')[0];
    audio.play();
    el.setAttribute('onclick', 'pause(this)');
}

function pause(el){
    var audio = $(el).prev('#player')[0];
    audio.pause();
    el.setAttribute('onclick', 'play(this)');
}
</script>
```